# Problems installing Rstudio. The program won't start although it is installed

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu, I recently installed succesfully R and other programs I use frequently. However, when trying to lauch R-studio I get the following error in the terminal:

```
rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What should I do to fix it?
I installed R-studio from the .deb file directly from the program website.

Comment: Fot Ubuntu 17.04, do the following as suggested in github https://github.com/toggl/toggldesktop/issues/1894#issuecomment-254427913

Comment: RStudio has a new preview out that doesn't require libgstreamer0.1 (it uses the new libgstreamer1.0 in Ubuntu 16). You can try it here: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/ This will become the stable build in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rstudio can't start because it needs the `libgstreamer` library.  You have to install it :

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0
```

and [related plug-ins](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207544237-Rstudio-99-won-t-launch-on-Ubuntu-15-10):

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, if the question isn't silly, what is the libgstreamer library? What is it needed for?

Comment: You can refer [here](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libgstreamer0.10-0) for a quick description of the `libgstreamer` package.

Comment: The reason you ran into this may be that Debian Testing dropped support for gstreamer 0.10. See [my answer on unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279426/30267) on how to proceed to re-add it.